# Closed form for $\int_1^\infty\frac{\operatorname dx}{\operatorname \Gamma(x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, closed-form, gamma-function

Is a closed form for $$\int\limits_1^{+\infty}\frac{\operatorname dx}{\operatorname \Gamma(x)}$$known?

I tried to find it, but all well-known integrals involving gamma-function (such as of $\log\Gamma(x)$ or the like) don't seem to be of much help here, just as standard representations of $\Gamma(x)$ as infinite products or integrals. Maybe someone came across this integral and remembers a reference?

Comment: See [Fransen-Robinson constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fransen-Robinson_constant).

Comment: @Lucian, thanks! Any thoughts how to reduce integral $\int_0^\infty$ to $\int_1^\infty$? It has an extra $\frac{1}{x}$ part...

Comment: There's no closed form for either of them.

Comment: See [Mu function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MuFunction.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Lucian said in comment this integral is related to [Fransén–Robinson constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson_constant). That is, 
$$F = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\, dx.$$

It is unknown whether $F$ can be expressed in closed form. I think because of this fact, your problem also doesn't have a known closed form.

I can tell you just some results about this problem. We could write your integral into the form:

$$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\, dx = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+x)}\, dx.$$

A numerical approximation of the integral is ([A247377](http://oeis.org/A247377))

$$2.2665345076998488350719638576782209184088297...$$

[Ramanujan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) [observed](http://books.google.hu/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA262&lpg=PA262&dq=Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson%20constant) that

$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{w^x}{\Gamma(1+x)} \, dx = e^w - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-we^y)}{y^2+\pi^2} \, dy.$$

For $w=1$ Ramanujan's formula gives an alternate form of you problem.

$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+x)} \, dx = e - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-e^y)}{y^2+\pi^2} \, dy.$$

And at last the last page of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606613.pdf) is also related.

---

I could get a connection between Fransén–Robinson constant and your integral. If we denote the Fransén–Robinson constant with $F$, then

$$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\, dx = F - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-e^y) \cdot (1+e^y)}{y^2 + \pi^2} \, dy.$$

But I couldn't find a closed form for this integral. Of course it is true, that

$$\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-e^y) \cdot (1+e^y)}{y^2 + \pi^2} \, dy.$$

Comment: As soon as you have $\exp\exp y$ in an integral a closed form is highly unlikely.

Comment: @Alizter Yes, but I thought possibly there is a closed form in term of [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\operatorname{Ei}$ function. But I couldn't find anything. Maybe someone else will give us a closed form for this.