# Closed-form of integrals containing double exponentials

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, closed-form

Are there closed forms for the following integrals?

$$\begin{align}
I_1(w) & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-we^y)}{y^2+\pi^2} dy, \\
I_2(w) & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-we^y+y)}{y^2+\pi^2} dy, \\
I_3(w,a) & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-we^y) \cdot (a+e^y)}{y^2 + \pi^2} \, dy,
\end{align}$$

where $w$ and $a$ are nonzero real parameters. I'm interested in special case of $w=1$, and $a=1$ or $a=2$.

The motivation of the problem is the [Fransén–Robinson constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson_constant), and in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/941764/153012) I've shown that $I_3(1,1) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)} dx.$ But maybe there is also a closed form for $I_3(1,1)$ perhaps in term of [exponential integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Some related integrals.

$$\begin{align}
& \int \exp\left(-e^{y}\right) dy = \operatorname{Ei}(-e^{y})+C, \\
& \int \exp\left(-we^{y}\right) dy = \operatorname{Ei}(-we^{y})+C, \\
& \int \exp\left(-e^{y}+y\right) dy = -\exp \left(-e^y \right)+C, \\
& \int \exp\left(-we^{y}+y\right) dy = \frac{-\exp \left(-we^y \right)}{w}+C,
\end{align}$$

where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: Presumably, $w>0$ or the integral is undefined/infinite.