# Continuous Poisson distribution: $\int_0^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}dn$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, poisson-distribution

I was thinking poission distribution, actually i like it. Then i thought there is no reason for some events to be integers. We can define occurences as half finished homeworks for example, or 3.7 apples etc.

[So when i give wolfram an example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28integral+3.2%5En%2Fn!*dn+,+from+1+to+4+%29+%2F+%28integral+3.2%5Em%2Fm!*dm+,+from+0+to+inf+%29), it actually calculates. Mean occurence of events is 3.2, what is the probability that i see this event to be between 1 and 4 ? It is about 0.6076

My question is that although wolfram calculates, i dont know and i couldnt find this integral (all density). Can it be calculated ?

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{n}}{n!}\,dn$$

Comment: You should look at Gamma distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution which is intimately linked to Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$, you are then asking about a closed form of
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{t^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx, \quad t>0. \tag1
$$ There is no known closed form of $(1)$, but this integral has been studied by Ramanujan who proved that

> $$
> \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^x}{\Gamma(1+x)} \, dx = e^t - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\large -te^x}}{x^2+\pi^2} \, dx, \quad t>0. \tag2
> $$

Some useful related links are [link 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212999/the-frans%C3%A9n-robinson-constant-as-a-limit-of-integrals), [link 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson_constant), [link 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938247/closed-form-for-int-1-infty-frac-operatorname-dx-operatorname-gammax).